# Program to give a PC's spec

Tags: windows, specifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any good tools for reporting on a computer’s specs?](https://superuser.com/questions/59143/are-there-any-good-tools-for-reporting-on-a-computers-specs)

Is there a program that could give me a summary of a PC's spec -  processor, ammount of RAM disk and so on.

Comment: duplicate of [Are there any good tools for reporting on a computer’s specs?](http://superuser.com/questions/59143/are-there-any-good-tools-for-reporting-on-a-computers-specs)

Answer (score 3):

[Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy)

Comment: Really nice little program. Freeware. Gives good detailed information

Answer (score 0):

the DirectX Diagnostic Tool gives a summary of the hardware in a system, and should be present on all Windows machines.

entering `dxdiag` into a Run box and pressing Enter/Return should pull it up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of the (now discontinued) AIDA32 programme. [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AIDA32) | [MajorGeeks Download](http://majorgeeks.com/download181.html).

Comment: We use AIDA64 and it's still awesome.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the WMIC command at the prompt on XP and later.

For example

```
wmic CPU list full /format:htable > COMPUTERSYSTEM.HTML
```

will dump CPU details to a HTML file.