# Is there a Windows-compatible tool for finding PC specifications that displays its report in a user-friendly way?

Tags: windows, diagnostic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any good tools for reporting on a computer’s specs?](https://superuser.com/questions/59143/are-there-any-good-tools-for-reporting-on-a-computers-specs)

I'm really looking for something that will display the highlights and hide the nitty-gritty details until I dig down.  The highlights are the stuff that would be on the outside of the PC box.  [SIW](http://www.gtopala.com/) is a bit more comprehensive than I would like.

So far [System Spec](http://www.alexnolan.net/software/sysspec.htm) is the best that I have found:

[image]

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy) and [Everest](http://www.lavalys.com/products/everest-pc-diagnostics) come to mind.

Comment: -- Speccy FTW !

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a gui, what about good old "[systeminfo.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491007.aspx)"? its built into every version of windows. The top lines are the general stuff you want, and further down is service packs and updates installed, etc.  It can export to CSV..

Or, for a more traditional GUI, that is also in every version of windows, there is [MSInfo32.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308549).

Comment: Not very user friendly, though

Answer (score 0):

It's probably more verbose than you want, but I use the free [Belarc Advisor](http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html).